# How to create product rating star on Product Page

Tags: magento2, review, product-page

I trying to look for a solution to show Rating Star on the Product Page, like the Product List Page. I tried adding it by creating a new Block on **catalog_product_view.xml** but not working 
[image: Rating Star on Product List Page]

**Rating Star on Product List Page**

Please help me with the solution for it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yep. I resolved my solution . This is my code .

1. Create catalog_product_view.xml on your theme.

    Add Block

> <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes"
> name="product.info.review.short"template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/review_short.phtml"/>

Create new file **review_short.phtml** on templates/view/review/ . Add code :

```
<?php
 /**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

/** @var $block Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes */

$listBlock= $block->getLayout()- 
>createBlock(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::class);
$templateType = 
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;

$_product = $block->getProduct();
if (!$_product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
return;
}
?>
<?= $listBlock->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
```

Done.
[image]